# Timelineview of all agenda files

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Is it possible to get a timeline view that combines the entries from all agenda files?

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: Ubuntu Linux 12.01

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the `org-timeline` function I'd say that, unfortunately, no. It only works on the file in the current buffer.

However it might be possible to create, progromatically, a file which contains all the relevant org files and then run `org-timeline` on that.